# Property recursively inherited from parent

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

### Abstract

Let's consider an entity which recursively inherits some property from it's parent in a tree like structure. So only the top level entities (roots) set such property.

I can think of two designs:

**A.** Set the field in the roots only. Rest have `NULL`.

**B.** Set the field in every entry.

It's not very clear to me, but I think that method **B** violates the third normal form. According to the simplistic definition [A Simple Guide to Five Normal Forms](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm) it doesn't (the non-key field - our property - is not about a non-key field, so we should be ok). However we have all the problems listed there:

- the same information is repeated in multiple records
- we can reach an inconsistent state if we update only some entities along a tree path.

Edit: I think however that it is about a non-key field: parent_id.

So I would very much appreciate a clarification here.

The problem with design **A** is that I don't know how to query the property value of non-root entries. I would need an arbitrary number of joins as the root is not at a fixed distance.  For instance how do you select all categories with type `t1` (see example bellow)?

How should such database be modeled? (maybe I missed another option)

### Example

Nested categories. Root categories set the `type` field. Rest inherit from their parent.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`category` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `parent_category_id` INT NULL,
  `type` ENUM('t1', 't2', 't3') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_category_category_idx` (`parent_category_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_category_parent_category`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_category_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`category` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Design **A** has `type` `NULL`. **B** has `type` `NOT NULL`.
`type` can be a FK to a `type table`.

```
A (t1) <- B <- C
X (t2) <- Y
```

**A**.

```
+----+------+------+-----------+
| id | name | type | parent_id |
+----+------+------+-----------+
|  1 |   A  |  t1  | NULL      |
|  2 |   B  | NULL |  1        |
|  3 |   C  | NULL |  2        |
|  4 |   X  |  t2  | NULL      |
|  5 |   Y  | NULL |  4        |
+----+------+------+-----------+
```

**B**.

```
+----+------+------+-----------+
| id | name | type | parent_id |
+----+------+------+-----------+
|  1 |   A  |  t1  | NULL      |
|  2 |   B  |  t1  |  1        |
|  3 |   C  |  t1  |  2        |
|  4 |   X  |  t2  | NULL      |
|  5 |   Y  |  t2  |  4        |
+----+------+------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL has no concept of inheritance, you have to do the work.  And that work will cost something -- either during INSERT/UPDATE (by propagating, as you suggest), or during SELECT (by following the tree to deduce what is inherited).

Either model "works".  We can't tell you which will be faster to run or simpler to code.

Comment: could you show how a SELECT could be done? I have no idea. Or at least what to search for on the web.

Comment: Can't be done with a single MySQL `SELECT`.  You would need a loop in your application language to walk up/down the tree, doing 1(?) `SELECT` per level.